# Ignore a "error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation."

Tags: typescript

I wanted to have shared utility function for dumping many scattered objects in the code like below, but it generates a TypeScript error. Is there any way to do this without repeating the shared code?
I tried this and this.
It seems to work fine in Chrome browser JS.

```
function formatthis() { return JSON.stringify(this); }
...
function whatever() {
  ...
  var something = { aa:234, bb:123, toString:formatthis };
  ...
  var something2 = { dfwerg:22, wer:11, toString:formatthis };
  ...
  var something3 = { sergw:55, qsfds:33, toString:formatthis };
  ...
  console.log('looks like '+something);
  ...
}
```

UPDATE: Example updated to stress reuse of method(s) among different random objects. It appears to work in Chrome browser (globally, in functions, with "use strict", etc), but // @ts-ignore always compiles but does not always work in Node, not sure why.

Comment: Why not *solve* the error instead of ignoring it?

Comment: `// @ts-ignore` will ignore a single line, but it's probably best to just type your variables rather than ignoring valid errors.

Comment: Thanks.
// @ts-ignore
works for my odd case where I wanted "this" to work for "any this" so I could reuse the code efficiently. There are lots of alternatives that all involve more code.
"this as any" or "<any>this" or etc seems to be applied to the return value of "this", and does not truly allow "any this".

Comment: @Codemeister `function whatever(this: any)` will allow for `this` to be anything. No real reason to do type assertions. Or ignoring compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

As other commenters have suggested, rather than ignoring the issue, you should [declare `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) as a parameter of your function. Something like:

```js
function formatthis(this: unknown) {
  return JSON.stringify(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
toString does not have parameters, so the above would require a little glue function to get "this" and pass it to formatthis instead of letting formatthis get the same "this" directly. This is one of many other methods that would compile but require more code.
As mentioned above, "// @ts-ignore" does allow "this' to truly be "any this" instead of requiring a known this the might be converted with <any> to anything.

Comment: @Codemeister You can _give_ an object's `toString` method a `this` parameter, and since you seem to be calling `formatthis` via `toString` already, it should take minimal effort. TypeScript inherently comes with writing more code than JavaScript. **OPINION TIME!** It is generally bad practice to use `// @ts-ignore` in place of the language features just for the sake of laziness ("[it would] require more code"). It should only be used when there is an issue with the transpiler, there is an issue with someone else's code, or using the language would make your own code too unclear.

Comment: Note: A method with a `this` parameter should not be passed an actual argument for `this`. `this` is inferred in context of where the method is called, like JavaScript. It is used only as a way of statically type-checking what `this` can be used with the method. By giving your method a parameter of `this: unknown`/`this: any`, you are telling the transpiler that it can be used in any context (i.e. with any `this`).